# Symfony2 Faker Populate ContextErrorException

Tags: php, symfony, faker

While running the php "app/console faker:populate" I am getting following error:

```
 [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException]                    
  Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Faker\ORM\Doctrine\EntityPopula  
  tor::execute() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface,   
  instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager given, called in /Users/hardeep/Docu  
  ments/Workspace/PHP/Websites/test.example.com/Symfony/vendor/fzaninotto/fake  
  r/src/Faker/ORM/Doctrine/Populator.php on line 71 and defined in /Users/har  
  deep/Documents/Workspace/PHP/Websites/test.example.com/Symfony/vendor/fzanin  
  otto/faker/src/Faker/ORM/Doctrine/EntityPopulator.php line 131
```

In my config.yml i have:

```
bazinga_faker:
    orm: doctrine
    entities:
        Example\RestApiBundle\Entity\Album:
            number: 10
        Example\RestApiBundle\Entity\Track:
            number: 10
        Example\RestApiBundle\Entity\Artist:
            number: 10
        Example\RestApiBundle\Entity\Language:
            number: 10
        Example\RestApiBundle\Entity\Playlist:
            number: 10
        Example\RestApiBundle\Entity\User:
            number: 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EntityManagerInterface` was added in Doctrine 2.4 and the `master` branch of Faker is already depending on it. So, either upgrade Doctrine to 2.4 or downgrade Faker from `master` to 1.2.